# Why is my queue.get() stuck on infinite loop when I try to load for second time?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, queue, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to run two functions simultaneously, and return from them their outputs. I have written the following code, but it only works to retrieve the output from either q1 or q2 **once**, but when I try a second time, I get stuck on an infinite loop. I do not understand why.

```
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Queue
import multiprocessing 
import time

def functionA(A, B):
    dictA=[]
    for i in list(range(A, B)):
        print(i, "from A")
        time.sleep(1)
        for p in list(range(0, 10)):
            dictA.append({i:p})
    return(dictA)

def functionB(C, D):
    dictB=[]
    for i in list(range(C, D)):
        print(i, "from B")
        time.sleep(1)
        for p in list(range(0, 10)):
            dictB.append({i:p})
    return(dictB)

#Create variables from global variables
def wrapper(func, args, queue):
    queue.put(func(*args))

q1, q2 = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue(), multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()

Thread(target=wrapper, args=(functionA, [0, 10], q1)).start()
Thread(target=wrapper, args=(functionB, [10, 20], q2)).start()
```

First time I try to get q1:

```
print(q1.get()) (0.9s)
[{0: 0}, {0: 1}, {0: 2}, {0: 3}, {0: 4}, {0: 5}, {0: 6}, {0: 7}, {0: 8}, {0: 9}, {1: 0}, {1: 1}, {1: 2}, {1: 3}, {1: 4}, {1: 5}, {1: 6}, {1: 7}, {1: 8}, {1: 9}, {2: 0}, {2: 1}, {2: 2}, {2: 3}, {2: 4}, {2: 5}, {2: 6}, {2: 7}, {2: 8}, {2: 9}, {3: 0}, {3: 1}, {3: 2}, {3: 3}, {3: 4}, {3: 5}, {3: 6}, {3: 7}, {3: 8}, {3: 9}, {4: 0}, {4: 1}, {4: 2}, {4: 3}, {4: 4}, {4: 5}, {4: 6}, {4: 7}, {4: 8}, {4: 9}, {5: 0}, {5: 1}, {5: 2}, {5: 3}, {5: 4}, {5: 5}, {5: 6}, {5: 7}, {5: 8}, {5: 9}, {6: 0}, {6: 1}, {6: 2}, {6: 3}, {6: 4}, {6: 5}, {6: 6}, {6: 7}, {6: 8}, {6: 9}, {7: 0}, {7: 1}, {7: 2}, {7: 3}, {7: 4}, {7: 5}, {7: 6}, {7: 7}, {7: 8}, {7: 9}, {8: 0}, {8: 1}, {8: 2}, {8: 3}, {8: 4}, {8: 5}, {8: 6}, {8: 7}, {8: 8}, {8: 9}, {9: 0}, {9: 1}, {9: 2}, {9: 3}, {9: 4}, {9: 5}, {9: 6}, {9: 7}, {9: 8}, {9: 9}]
```

Second time I try to get q1 its stuck on infinite loop:

```
print(q1.get())
.......
```

Comment: You only *put* one thing in the queue.

Comment: I see, sorry I am completely new to threading and queues. Even if I repeat the ```queue.put(func(*args))``` two times in the wrapper function, after a few reloads, the ```print(queue.get())``` will get stuck on infinite loop though.

Comment: Why are you mixing threads and `multiprocessing`? Those are two different things. You should use a `queue.Queue`, not a `multiprocessing.Queue`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I have changed ```multiprocessing.Queue``` to ```queue.Queue```. Everything else looks ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created 2 queues `q1` and `q2`, and according to what you said you only do `q1.get()` and you try to do is twice while what you need to do is:

```
print(q1.get())
print(q2.get())
```

Or you can use 1 queue and then you can do `q1.get()` twice.

Comment: and because you are using `Threads` and not `multiprocessing` you can just create a global variable and store the result there (threads has shared memory, unlike processes, each process has it's own memory that is shared between the threads in that process, that's way you have `queue` in `multiprocessing` and not in `threading`).

Comment: I tried to create a global variable in the thread functions, and it works when in main.py, but when these functions are imported from other.py the global variables get lost. That's why I am currently trying this approach... The queue allows me to retrieve the variables, whereas threading did not allow me to do so.